# How to create a tooltip only when ellipsis is active ? I want the solution only in CSS

Tags: css

The following code gives a long text , but I want as tooltip .

```css
.truncate {
  max-width: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.truncate:hover {
  text-overflow: clip;
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<span class="truncate"> HERE</span>
```

Comment: use title attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use title attribute not hover style.

```css
.truncate {
  max-width: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<span class="truncate" title="HERE is my sample text HERE is my sample text"> 
    HERE is my sample text HERE is my sample text
</span>
```

Comment: Question contains condition "only when ellipsis is active"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the tooltip, you can use data attribute.

```css
.tooltip {
     position: relative;
}
 .tooltip-bottom:hover::after {
     content: attr(data-tooltip);
     padding: 4px 8px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 100%;
     white-space: nowrap;
     z-index: 1;
     background-color: #000;
     color: #fff;
}
 .truncate {
     max-width: 100px;
     overflow: hidden;
     display: inline-block;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<span class="tooltip tooltip-bottom" data-tooltip="HERE is my sample text HERE is my sample text"> 
  <p class="truncate">HERE is my sample text HERE is my sample text</p>
</span>
```